# How can use ROW_NUMBER in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm a new to SQL Server and has a this query:

```
SELECT distinct top 10 ExecuteDate  
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]  
ORDER BY ExecuteDate  DESC
```

I should be use the `Row_Number` in that query, how can I write that query?

thanks all.

Comment: We have **no** idea what purpose you want to put `ROW_NUMBER()` to.

Comment: add more details about your question, row_number order by what and do you want partition and if yes then on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a number for each row and the ExecuteDate  should be distinct:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT ExecuteDate  FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
)
SELECT TOP 10 ExecuteDate, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ExecuteDate   DESC)
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ExecuteDate  DESC
```

or with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ExecuteDate, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC)
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
GROUP BY ExecuteDate
ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC
```

---

Maybe you want to see the whole record, but only the first of each ExecuteDate-Group. Then this query will work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ExecuteDate, 
           RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExecuteDate 
                                        ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC)
    FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
)
SELECT TOP 10 ExecuteDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN_DESC = 1
ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC
```

Instead of only the column `ExecuteDate` you can list all. But `ExecuteDate` is the column to group by and you haven't told us which column you want to use for the ordering of each group, so which row of each ExecuteDate-group you want to see. So currently this query returns an arbitrary row of each group. Change the `PARTITION BY ExecuteDate ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC` to f.e. `PARTITION BY ExecuteDate ORDER BY AnotherDateOrIdColumn DESC` to get a more meaningful result.

Comment: Thanks,but how can use where cluase,for example where row=1?

Comment: Why do you need that? That's not a `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY ExecuteDate   DESC)`. Every row-number is distinct above. If you only want the first row then use `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: in my db return the two values distinct :1395/6/17 and 1395/6/11 ,when use top just show me   1395/6/17,and want access to   1395/6/11 value too.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi: ive edited my answer, maybe that is what you are loking for

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like these :

```
SELECT distinct  top 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC), ExecuteDate  
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]  
ORDER BY ExecuteDate  DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ExecuteDate
FROM (
    SELECT  ExecuteDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ExecuteDate ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC) as RN
    FROM [GetOnlineBills]  
) as t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC
```

Or:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ExecuteDate
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ExecuteDate 
    FROM [GetOnlineBills]  
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ExecuteDate ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC)
) as t
ORDER BY ExecuteDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks but this WHERE RN = 1 show me two row's!

Comment: And the second query? `SELECT DISTINCT ExecuteDate FROM [GetOnlineBills]  ` how much rows it will return

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ExecuteDate FROM [GetOnlineBills] return me two record,i want with where access to all row,for example row=1,row=2

Comment: You got 2 different `ExecuteDate`s and what should `TOP 10` return?? :)